# How to count the number of occurrences of a attribute in a string of another table

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, count

Im struggling with a complex SQL query, I want to count how many times attribute x in table 1 shows up in a string in table 2.
so t1 has a name attribute and t2 has an participants attribute and a project attribute

```
ID | Name
---------
0  | Bob
1  | Bill
2  | Jill 

T2
Project | Participants
-----------------
0       | Bob, Bill
1       | Bob, Jill
2       | Bob

Output
Bob  3
Bill 1
Jill 1
```

Participants in t2 is a string. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I would recommend to desgin table T2 to be in first normal form:
[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: You are struggling because the query will be complex, and that will be because table T2 is not in first normal form. If the "Participants" string comes from some external source, so you have no control over it - that is fine, but it shouldn't be stored that way in a relational database, like Oracle. The string should be broken down into its component tokens, and the result is what should be stored. As it is, you will have to do the "tokenization" (normalization) yourself, in every query, and that's complex, and you will struggle with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should primarily focus on fixing your data model. Each participant to each project should be stored as a separate row rather than munged in a delimited string, possibly referencing the other table through a foreign key constraint:

```
project_id    participant_id
         0                 0   -- Bob
         0                 1   -- Bill
         1                 0   -- Bob
         1                 2   -- Jill
         2                 0   -- Bob
```

Then you could efficiently phrase the query:

```
select t1.*
    (select count(*) from table2 t2 where t2.participant_id = t1.id) cnt
from table1 t1
```

That said, given your current layout, one option uses string functions:

```
select t1.*, 
    (
        select count(*) 
        from table2 t2 
        where ', ' || t2.participants || ', ' like '%, ' || t1.name || ', %'
    ) cnt
from table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the participants only appear once in each project then you can use:

```sql
SELECT t1.Name,
       COUNT( t2.Participants) AS cnt
FROM   t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
       ON ( ', ' || t2.Participants || ', ' LIKE '%, ' || t1.Name || ', %' )
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 ( ID, Name ) AS
SELECT 0, 'Bob'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Bill' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Jill' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Tim'  FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE T2 ( Project, Participants ) AS
SELECT 0, 'Bob, Bill' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Bob, Jill' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Bob' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> NAME | CNT
> :--- | --:
> Bill |   1
> Jill |   1
> Bob  |   3
> Tim  |   0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3cfab8666b59374404eedd5a502ac3d5)*